# localization image laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-localization

what code should I write for localization in laravel 5 for an image?

The following code I used to string

ENGLISH lang

```html
       <?php
   return [
      'namaSaya' => 'MY NAME',
      'registrasi' => ' REGISTRASION'      
   ];
```

INDONESIA lang

```html
       <?php 
return [
      'namaSaya' => 'NAMA SAYA',
      'registrasi' => ' REGISTRASI'      
   ];
```

and the code that I use to display

```
{{ trans('content.namaSaya') }}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just like this:

```
<?php 
return [
  'namaSaya' => 'NAMA SAYA',
  'registrasi' => ' REGISTRASI',
  'sampleImg' => url('to/img_in_certain_lang.jpg')
];
```

and then just:

```
<img src="@lang('content.sampleImg')" />
```

Comment: Wow thanks for that Filip Koblański . That code works nice.